# error : virNetSocketReadWire:1792 : End of file while reading data: Input/output error

Tags: libvirt, openstack

libvirt version - 8.0.0

OS - Centos 8 Stream

Kernel - Linux 4.18.0-408.el8.x86_64 #3 SMP Mon Aug 21 12:19:16 EDT 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Openstack Version - Yoga 24.1.1

I am running openstack setup, post running IO for couple of days, I am seeing input/output error in libvirtd.logs. Not sure how to find root cause and solve it.

Comment: This is not enough information to be able to understand what's going on. Do you see errors in nova-compute.log as well? Do VMs fail or are not reachable anymore? More context is required.

Comment: No errors in nova logs. VMs on host freeze and not able to ping any of them.

Comment: There are reports stating that the libvirt error message is only a consequence of a VM closing the connection unexpectedly. So you'll probably have to troubleshoot with the VMs and check what's going on before the freeze. What's your storage back-end?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.